# Watch Live TV from Windows Media Center on a remote Computer? Not in the same house (I do have VPN)

Tags: windows-7, tv, desktop-computer, tuner-card

I have a computer running a USB Tuner in one house. I want to watch it in another location. I have tried Mediaportal (didn't work) and Remote Potato. I currently use Splashtop to stream it to another computer and iPad. I would prefer something that was full screen.

Comment: What specific version of Windows 7 are you running it on, and what OS are you using on the other computer?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate. 2012 Mac Mini Server. I can run it on Mac OSX, Windows 7, Android, iOS.

Comment: To clarify: The 2012 Mac Mini Server that you mention is the software that you're using to share it?

Comment: The 2012 Mac Mini has the tuner card plugged in. It is the computer that will do the sharing. It is running Windows Media Center to show live TV.

Comment: Do you already have it set up so that the Windows Media Center works to watch live tv on the Windows computer?

Comment: Yes.11characters